# how to convert a Iterator[Long] to Iterator[String] in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a requirement where I have to convert a Iterator[Long] to Iterator[String] in scala.
Please let me know how can I do it

Comment: Q&A for producing a true `Iterator[Long]` posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72937656/how-to-produce-a-true-iterarorlong-in-scala/72937657#72937657)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just like any other collection use [map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Iterator). For example:

```
scala> val ls = List(1,2,3).toIterator
ls: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> ls.map(_.toString) //it was map(x+""). see comments on why it is bad
res0: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> res0.next
res1: String = 1

scala> res0.next
res2: String = 2

scala> res0.next
res3: String = 3
```

Comment: I think `ls.map(_.toString)` would be a bit more clear.

Comment: Ugh, `+""` is awkward, unclear, and relies on [one of the worst parts](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-194) of the Scala language. `ls.map(_.toString)` would be at least a little less horrible.

Comment: The idiom is `.map("" + _ )` to handle `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> List(1,2,3).toIterator.map(_.toString)
res1: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> List(1,2,3).toIterator.map(_.toString).mkString(", ")
res2: String = 1, 2, 3
```