# How to produce a true `Iterator[Long]` in Scala

Tags: scala, iterator, unfold

I came across this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293035/how-to-convert-a-iteratorlong-to-iteratorstring-in-scala) looking for a way to create an `Iterator[Long]`.

Currently the Scala SDK does not have any Iterator *constructor* that produces an `Iterator[Long]`.

Other collection types may (unverified) provide some kind of constructor, yielding a value from which a call to `.iterator` may produce a `Iterator[Long]`, but how can you guarantee the *'lazy and forgetful'* semantics of an Iterator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this lets you iterate through all (positive) Longs sequentially:

```
Iterator.iterate(1L)(_ + 1)
```

Alternatively, this produces an infinite iterator of random Longs:

```
Iterator.continually(util.Random.nextLong)
```

This generates an infinite sequence of Fibonacci numbers:

```
Iterator.iterate(1L -> 1L) { case (a,b) => (b, a+b) }.map(_._1)
```

Comment: I would also mention `unfold` which is very useful to create infinite lazy collections like `Iterator` & `LazyList`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am not aware of anything you can do with `unfold` that you couldn't do with `iterate` (plus, perhaps, `takeWhile`), so ... Occam's razor :)

Comment: Thanks [@Dima](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4254517/dima). For the life of me, I do not know how I missed/did not see `Iterator.iterate(...)(...)`; may delete the whole post

Answer (score 1):

Probably in most cases `Iterator.from(<Int>).map(_.toLong)` would suffice, but this will wrap at `Int.MaxValue`;
if you are testing an API that truly handles `Longs` and you want coverage extending over the domain of numbers greater than `Int.MaxValue`, then this is clearly inadequate.

`Unfold` to the rescue:

```scala
package code

object Code {
  implicit class IteratorFromLongOps(val obj: Iterator.type) extends AnyVal {
    def from(start: Long): Iterator[Long] = Iterator.unfold(start)(s => Some((s, s+1)))
  }
}
```

```scala
scala> import code.Code._
import code.Code._

scala> Iterator.from(Int.MaxValue - 1).take(4).foreach(println)
2147483646
2147483647
-2147483648
-2147483647

scala> Iterator.from((Int.MaxValue - 1).toLong).take(4).foreach(println)
2147483646
2147483647
2147483648
2147483649
```

Comment: Interesting, using `unfold` as Luis mentioned. Is there any difference in this case between `unfold` and `iterate` ?